# Как создать генератор чисел с использованием регулярных выражений?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо создать генератор чисел. Знаю про функцию `rand()`, что можно сделать только с ее помощью, но все устроено так, что необходимо сделать регулярку.

В общем, человек посылает на сервер через форму текст = `!rand 1-10`. Сервер должен построить `rand(1,10)` и вывести результат. Как это реализовать?

Примерно код должен выглядеть так:

```
if(mb_strtolower($_POST['text']) == "регулярка"){ //регулярка - "!rand выражение"
    $rand = rand(); //как-то взять числа из регулярки
    echo $rand;
}
```

Буду очень благодарен помощи!

Comment: Автор, за вас всю работу сделать надо, или есть какой-то конкретный вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать

```
preg_match("/rand=(.*)-(.*)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Маска `rand=(.*)-(.*)`

для `rand=1-10` результат

```
array(3
   0    =>  rand=1-10
   1    =>  1
   2    =>  10
)
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ciU